# Time of Occurrence of Events

Tags: possible-worlds, david-lewis

I'm wrestling with the notion of events in indeterministic worlds. Suppose that given an event type and a world we can in principle tell if the event occurs in that world. (Indeed we could represent an event type as a subset of possible worlds). Further suppose one can tell if two worlds are identical up to some point in time. I am tempted to conclude that one can then define the time of occurrence of an event type in a given world. However, I'm bothered by the consequence that events would "occur" as soon as they become inevitable.

The only fix I've been able to find involves dealing with partial worlds -- i.e. worlds with histories only up to some point in time -- but this seems terribly ad-hoc and at odds with Lewis' elegant notion of a possible world as encompassing of time and space which I would like to retain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the technical meaning of "event type" and "world?" Are you referring to some particular theory or paper? Are you accounting for relatavistic simultaneity issues? If A precedes B according to one observer, B can precede A according to another. That throws a wrench into your analysis I think. But I'd like to get a better understanding of your terms and framework.

Comment: I would also like to understand "suppose one can tell if two worlds are identical..." that implies the ability to specify two worlds.  How you handle that will have a marked effect on your answers.

Comment: @user4894: For technical meaning of "world" I follow Lewis' 1986 _On The Plurality of Worlds_. I am proposing that an event type may be represented as a subset of the space of possible worlds. Good point about relativistic issues, I have not accounted for them, though that would be desirable. Any recommended reading?